# Can't access the member function of member variable

Tags: c++, class

I do different implementation, some of them works. but the other not.
Just wondering why the other doesn't work.
Marking different with comments
Plz focus on  instantiation of vector .

sample input

```
2 2 1
Alice Bob Daisy Emma Kenny
3
0 Administering Medications
0 Providing Wound Care
0 Promoting Mobility
0 0
1 1
0 1
1 -1
2 3
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 1 1
```

sample output
but my codes output some addresses or data for checking

```
name: Kenny
doctor: Alice
tasks: 
Administering Medications Daisy 
Providing Wound Care Daisy 
Promoting Mobility Emma
```

wrong method - while outputing the name of task , the program aborts abnormally.
Doesn't output the following lines.

```
Administering Medications Daisy 
Providing Wound Care Daisy 
Promoting Mobility Emma
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person {
    public:
        Person(std::string n){
                name=n;}
        std::string getName(){
            return name;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
};

class Staff : public Person {
    public:
        Staff(std::string n): Person(n) {}
        void setSupervisor(Staff* s){
            if (s!=NULL ) supervisor = s;
            else supervisor =NULL;
        }
        Staff* getSupervisor(){
            return supervisor;
        }

    private:
        Staff* supervisor;
};

class Doctor : public Staff {
    public:
        Doctor(std::string n): Staff(n) {}
};

class Nurse : public Staff {
    public:
        Nurse(std::string n): Staff(n) {}
};

class Task {
    public:
        Task(std::string n){
                name=n;}
        std::string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        void setName(std::string n){
            name = n;
        }
        void setNurse(Nurse* n){
            nurse = n;
        }
        Nurse* getNurse(){
            return nurse;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        Nurse* nurse;
};

class Patient : public Person {
    public:
        Patient(std::string n): Person(n) {}
        void setDoctor(Doctor* d){
            doctor = d;
        }
        Doctor* getDoctor(){
            return doctor;
        }
        void addTask(Task* t){
            tasks.push_back(t);
        }
        int Tasksize(){
            return tasks.size();
        }
        Task* OneTask(int i){
            return tasks[i];
        }
    
    private:
        std::vector<Task*> tasks;
        Doctor* doctor;
        
};


int main(void) {
    int Dnum, Nnum, Pnum;
    std::cin >> Dnum >> Nnum >> Pnum;
    std::vector<Doctor> doctors;
    std::vector<Nurse> nurses;
    std::vector<Patient> patients;
    for( int i =0 ; i<Dnum ;i++){
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        doctors.emplace_back(Doctor(name));
    }

    for( int i =0 ; i<Nnum ;i++){
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        nurses.emplace_back(Nurse(name));
    }
    for( int i =0 ; i<Pnum ;i++){
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        patients.emplace_back(Patient(name));
    }
    int task;
    std::cin>>task;
    //std::vector<Task> tasks(task);
    std::vector<Task> tasks; //instantiate vector<Task> with zero length
    for(int i=0 ; i<task ; i++){
        int Pid;
        std::string Tname;
        std::cin >> Pid;
        scanf(" ");
        getline(std::cin,Tname);  

        tasks.emplace_back(Task(Tname));  //put Task(Tname) on the vector<Task>
        std::cout<<tasks[i].getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<<&tasks[i]<<"\n";        
        patients[Pid].addTask(&(tasks[i]));
    }


    for( int i =0 ; i<Nnum ;i++){
        int yee, xer;
        std::cin >> yee >> xer;
        nurses[yee].setSupervisor(&(doctors[xer]));
    }
    for( int i =0 ; i<Dnum ;i++){
        int yee, xer;
        std::cin >> yee >> xer;
        doctors[yee].setSupervisor(&(doctors[xer]));
    } 
    int DtoD, DtoN;
    std::cin>>DtoD>> DtoN;
    for ( int i =0 ; i<DtoD ;i++){
        int xer, yee, p;
        std::cin >> xer >> yee >>p;
        if( &(doctors[xer]) ==  doctors[yee].getSupervisor() ){
            patients[p].setDoctor(&(doctors[yee]));
        }
    } 
    for ( int i =0 ; i<DtoN ;i++){
        int t, xer, yee;
        std::cin >> t >> xer >> yee ;
        if( &(doctors[xer]) ==  nurses[yee].getSupervisor() ){
            tasks[t].setNurse(&(nurses[yee]));
        }
    } 
    // for(int i=0 ; i<task ; i++){
    //     std::cout<<tasks[i].getName()<<"\n";
    // }

    for( int i =0 ; i<Pnum ;i++){
        std::cout<< "name: " <<patients[i].getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "doctor: " <<(patients[i].getDoctor())->getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "tasks: " <<"\n";
        int n= patients[i].Tasksize();
        //std::vector<Task*> Ts= patients[i].tasks;
        //std::cout<< n<<"\n";
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++){
            std::cout<< (patients[i].OneTask(j))<<"\n";
            std::cout<<  patients[i].OneTask(j)->getName()<<" " << (patients[i].OneTask(j)->getNurse())->getName() <<"\n";

        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

successful method 1

```
class Task {
    public:
        // Task(std::string n){
        //         name=n;}
        std::string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        void setName(std::string n){
            name = n;
        }
        void setNurse(Nurse* n){
            nurse = n;
        }
        Nurse* getNurse(){
            return nurse;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        Nurse* nurse;
};



int main(void) {

    int task;
    std::cin>>task;
    std::vector<Task> tasks(task);  //instantiate vector<Task> with specific length

    for(int i=0 ; i<task ; i++){
        int Pid;
        std::string Tname;
        std::cin >> Pid;
        scanf(" ");
        getline(std::cin,Tname);
        //std::cout << Tname <<"\n";

        tasks[i].setName(Tname);
        // tasks.emplace_back(Task(Tname));
        std::cout<<tasks[i].getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<<&tasks[i]<<"\n";        
        patients[Pid].addTask(&(tasks[i]));
    }

    for( int i =0 ; i<Pnum ;i++){
        std::cout<< "name: " <<patients[i].getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "doctor: " <<(patients[i].getDoctor())->getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "tasks: " <<"\n";
        int n= patients[i].Tasksize();
        //std::vector<Task*> Ts= patients[i].tasks;
        //std::cout<< n<<"\n";
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++){
            std::cout<< (patients[i].OneTask(j))<<"\n";
            std::cout<<  patients[i].OneTask(j)->getName()<<" " << (patients[i].OneTask(j)->getNurse())->getName() <<"\n"; //can't run getName()

        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

successful method 2

```
class Task {
    public:
        Task(std::string n):name(n){
                }
        std::string getName(){
            return name;
        }
        void setName(std::string n){
            name = n;
        }
        void setNurse(Nurse* n){
            nurse = n;
        }
        Nurse* getNurse(){
            return nurse;
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        Nurse* nurse;
};


int main(void) {

    int task;
    std::cin>>task;
    //std::vector<Task> tasks(task);
    std::vector<Task*> tasks;  //instantiate vector<Task*> with zero length
    for(int i=0 ; i<task ; i++){
        int Pid;
        std::string Tname;
        std::cin >> Pid;
        scanf(" ");
        getline(std::cin,Tname);

        tasks.emplace_back(new Task(Tname)); //new Task and put it on the vector<Task*>
        std::cout<<tasks[i]->getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<<tasks[i]<<"\n";        
        patients[Pid].addTask((tasks[i]));
    }



    for( int i =0 ; i<Pnum ;i++){
        std::cout<< "name: " <<patients[i].getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "doctor: " <<(patients[i].getDoctor())->getName()<<"\n";
        std::cout<< "tasks: " <<"\n";
        int n= patients[i].Tasksize();
        //std::vector<Task*> Ts= patients[i].tasks;
        //std::cout<< n<<"\n";
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++){
            std::cout<< (patients[i].OneTask(j))<<"\n";
            std::cout<<  patients[i].OneTask(j)->getName()<<" " << (patients[i].OneTask(j)->getNurse())->getName() <<"\n";

        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (s!=NULL ) supervisor = s; else supervisor =NULL;` --> `supervisor = s;`

Comment: *"doesn't work. ..."* What does that mean?

Comment: _patients[Pid].addTask(&(tasks[i]));_  Can't do that. The pointer will be invalidated when the task vector reallocated. Store/use the index instead - presuming you never rearrange the order of things in the task vector..

Comment: Post the code that reproduces the error instead of code that [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/95xnTq7TT). Also you should remove the unnecessary code that doesn't contribute to the problem/error. See [mcve]

Comment: Worry about the same thing for your pointer members for your other classes as well. (They may work if the vector is entirely populated before you start taking addresses of vector entries, but it is a risky approach. In the tack case you start taking addresses of task vector elements while populating the vector.)

Comment: Avi Berger,  patients[Pid].addTask(&(tasks[i]));  it works on successful method 1

Comment: It may appear to work at times. That doesn't mean it isn't a problem. When you add an element to a vector and it is at its current capacity, it allocates a new, larger block and moves all the existing entries into it. All the previous addresses are now invalid. It may not be the problem that you are looking for. I stopped reading when I spotted this problem.

Comment: Avi Berger, thanks for responding, but it's restricted that " std::vector<Task*> tasks; " in the patient class and it has to be private member. How can we do it right with this restriction?

Comment: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) may be appropriate. Not sure what this sequence is about: `std::cin >> Pid; scanf(" "); getline(std::cin,Tname);` You also have no error checking on any input so if it is parsing incorrectly and that causes an attempt to read a name into an int for example, you won't know where it happened, only that your program behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: Retired Ninja, Thanks for the advice, I learned another trick. According to the problem I encountered, the input format is  number + " " + name

Comment: Well, you seem to already have that. Your successful method 1 makes sure the task vector starts off with enough memory before adding tasks to it so that it won't have to reallocate. This is vulnerable to breaking in the future if the program needs to be revised and adds more tasks to the task vector later. Your successful method 2 dynamically allocates the tasks so they don't move. This approach brings up memory management issues - lifetime and memory leaks. Addressing those "nicely" may be beyond where you are in class now. You never _delete_ the Task objects you _new_ in method 2.

Comment: Ah, it works on method one since you pre-allocated enough memory before starting to add elements in successful method 1. I hadn't read through everything. (late edit)